# How to disable mouseevents to specific div

Tags: angularjs

```
<form id="header-search" class="container"  ng-controller="controller"  ng-mouseup="hoverComboDropDown()" >

<div class="comboDropDownBtn downButtonBGColor" id="id_DropDownBtn_list"  ng-click="dropDown()" ng-disabled="true">//form Layout
</form>

function hoverComboDropDown(){
..operation A;

}
function dropdown(){
..operation b;`enter code here`
}
```

//while calling operation a is overlapping with operation b. like first operation a is getting called later operation b how can i disable overla

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want but maybe try to stopPropagation() at some point? Or preventDefault()?

Comment: Very unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear question, but from what I can understand you shold add $event into your dropDown function. Like this:

```
<div class="comboDropDownBtn downButtonBGColor" id="id_DropDownBtn_list"  ng-click="dropDown($event)" ng-disabled="true">
```

Then you should add into your angular function following lines:

```
function dropDown(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  // your additional code
}
```